# Why can't I create shortcuts Ctrl+U and Ctrl+Shift+U in PowerShell ISE?

Tags: windows-7, powershell-ise

I am trying to assign

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

to some PowerShell ISE Addonmenu functions,  but say seem to be assigned to some Windows function.

I didn't find them in current online shortcut lists either or are there some applications which can create global shortcuts which are used even when other application have the focus?

**Edit:**

I changed the title, after recognizing, that this is a PowerShell ISE problem and no general Windows problem.

and here is the code

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Test 1",{Write-host 'test 1'}, "CTRL+SHIFT+U") 
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Test 2",{Write-host 'test 2'}, "CTRL+U") 


Exception calling "Add" with "3" argument(s): "The menu 'Test 1' uses shortcut 'Ctrl+Shift+U', which is already in use by the menu or editor functionality.
Parametername: shortcut"
At line:1 char:52
+ $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add <<<< ("Test 1",{Write-host 'test 1'}, "CTRL+SHIFT+U") 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodTargetInvocation

Exception calling "Add" with "3" argument(s): "The menu 'Test 2' uses shortcut 'Ctrl+U', which is already in use by the menu or editor functionality.
Parametername: shortcut"
At line:2 char:52
+ $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add <<<< ("Test 2",{Write-host 'test 2'}, "CTRL+U") 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodTargetInvocation
```

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser?? CTRL+U sounds like undo to me, and CTRL+SHIFT+U sounds like a possible redo.

Comment: No undo in PowerShell ISE is CTRL-Z

Comment: Where and how are you trying to assign these shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after being able to create such menus in PowerGUI Script Editor, I found the solution.

This is no Windows problem, but just a pure PowerShell ISE problem.

Fact is, that ISE uses

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to convert a selection to uppercase and

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to convert it to lowercase.

The mystery is, that there is no menu showing these two functions and their shortcuts.

Comment: But Visual Studio 2010 shows these functions in its Edit|Advanced menu. It would be better if ISE does the same.